# Possible causes of Generic Server Error message for SoapException

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap

I am currently accessing a web service.  The only message I got from the thrown exception is "Server Error."  During the past tests, the only exceptions I encountered have HTTP error codes in it i.e. 401 Unauthorized, 403 Forbidden, etc.  This one doesn't have it and it is really generic.  Any experiences on what the possible causes are?

The exception occurs when CredentialCache.Add is called.  I am using Basic authentication type.

Thanks in advance for any help related to this question.

I am using C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server Error is HTTP error code 500. It usually means that there was an unhandled exception on the server. Check the event logs on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

I would read this as an problem on the service provider's end. Maybe a temporary problem? I would want to look in the logs and other diagnostics for that Web Service provider - easy if it's yours, or they are just down the corridor maybe. Otherwise I hope you have a supportive relationship!

It will  be annoying for you if it transpires that some particular combination of your input data is causing the issue and the error isn't telling you that.